# https and CodeIgniter problems

Tags: database, codeigniter

Once I go to my website using `https://`, the CodeIgniter database loading does not work anymore. This is part of the error shown:

```
 Message: PDO::__construct(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/students/550067/www/db/Database.sqlite) is not within the allowed path(s): (.)
```

This is the config file:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlite:/home/students/550067/www/db/Database.sqlite',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'DateBase.sqlite',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

What could be the problem?